# Declare a global object for multiple functions

Tags: php, object, mysqli

So I have a list of functions that i'm using in a web app. Most of the functions however, make calls to a database class. Here are two functions for example:

```
function add_post($userid,$body,$cat_id,$user_link){            //This function inserts new posts into the db

$db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db');
$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$insertData = array(
   'user_id' => $userid,
    'body' => $body,
    'stamp' => $now,
    'cat_id' => $cat_id,
    'link' => $user_link
    );

$db->insert('posts', $insertData);

}



function grab_username($userid){                    //This function takes a user id, and returns the associated user_name

$db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db');

$params = array($userid);
$results = $db->rawQuery("SELECT username FROM users WHERE id = ?", $params);

//print_r($results);

foreach($results as $arrays){

    foreach($arrays as $name){
        return $name;
    }
   }

}
```

the problem is that I am constantly writing the line:

```
$db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db');
```

Is there a way I can declare the variable globally, have something more like this:

```
$db = new MysqliDb('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'my_db');

function add_post($userid,$body,$cat_id,$user_link){            //This function inserts new posts into the db

$now = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

$insertData = array(
   'user_id' => $userid,
    'body' => $body,
    'stamp' => $now,
    'cat_id' => $cat_id,
    'link' => $user_link
    );

  global $db->insert('posts', $insertData);

}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple ways to handle this but the best implementation can vary depending on the structure and needs of your action application.

You mentioned a global variable which would work, but is typically considered poor structure:

```
someFunction(){
  global $db;
  $db->insert('posts', $insertData);
}
```

Another method, which is slightly cleaner but still not as well organized is to pass the `$db` connection to the functions:

```
function myFunction( $db, ... ){
    $db->query( // etc );
}
myFunction( $db );
```

A better version of this would be to organize your related functions in a class, and then inject the database:

```
class Posts {
  public function listPosts( $db, ... ){
    $db->query( // etc );
  }
  public function getPost( $db, ... ){
    $db->query( // etc );
  }
}

$posts = new Posts();
$posts->listPosts();
```

However, you can also decide to make these `static` methods, you could pass `$db` to the class constructor and store it, there are many choices.

You could also make a central wrapper class of your own that returns the connection. There are a million implementations but it's hard to specifically recommend one without knowing more about your application structure, how your classes share resources, how the application bootstraps everything - if it does. Etc

Comment: I hope you are not serious. Create a separate db connection for the every class?

Comment: If he's only using a single instance of this class, as I personally interpret his question, this would be fine. If he's using multiple instances then obviously dependency injection or some central way of getting a single db instance is better.

Comment: this is not the only class in his application.

Comment: Pretty likely, however I see no information either way aside from his use of the `MysqliDb` class.

Comment: and in all these classes he is supposed to create a new db connection, based on your answer.

Comment: I had already amended the answer to address your concerns. You're accusing me of making assumptions about his code structure but you're doing just the same. I'll try my best to keep my answer clear as to what needs to change based on implementation but who knows, he could have a thousand objects with factory patterns which need to share a database connection, or he could have a page consisting purely of global function calls.

Comment: I am accusing you for writing an answer of unacceptable quality and destructive consequences.

Comment: I've expanded the answer to try to prepare OP for the wide variety of ways a shared resource can be implemented.

Comment: There is no shared resource in your answer. If you consider your class such a resource, then you just moved the scope problem one level above, but it remains the same.

Comment: I've given no specifics as to the origin of `$db`. Please let me know when you've answered OPs question yourself.

Comment: In your older answer you have given the origin all right. And it was unacceptable, as it were creating a new connection for the every object. In your current one you have a very strange idea that db handler can be passed in constructor only for static classes. There is no point in answering a question that has been answered a gigazillion times already. However, it's all right with your answer. This site is not to share knowledge, but to gain points. You've got yours - so, it's all right.

Answer (score -1):

Try This:

**db.php**

```
class DB
{

   public $conn;
   private static $instance;

   private function __construct()
   {
     $server = 'localhost';
     $user = 'root';
     $pass = 'root';
     $database = 'my_db';

     $this->conn = mysqli_connect($server,$user,$pass,$database);
   }

   public function query($sql)
   {
     $result = mysqli_query($this->conn,$sql);
     return $result;

   }

   public static function getInstance()
   {
     if (!isset(self::$instance))
     {
         $object = __CLASS__;
         self::$instance = new $object;
     }
     return self::$instance;
   }
}
```

Now in any page you can do:

```
require("db.php");
$dbh = DB::getInstance();
$sql = "your sql query ..";
$dbh->query($sql);
```